# Apart from Frank & Nancy Sinatra, have any other parent & child both individually made it to number one in the singles charts?

Tags: chart-success, number-ones

Frank Sinatra has a bunch of number ones (including apparently the first Billboard #1, *I'll Never Smile Again*); Nancy made it with *These Boots Are Made for Walkin'*.

Have any other parent and child both individually made it to number one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Billy Ray Cyrus - "Achy Breaky Heart" (1992) #1 US Country

Miley Cyrus - "Wrecking Ball" (2013) #1 Billboard Top 100
              "The Climb" (2009) #1 Adult Contemporary

Comment: My sincere apologies for not +1 on this, valid though your answer is - it's just my internal 'taste filter' will simply not allow me ;-) [oh, I +1'd anyway, would be cruel otherwise]

Comment: Lol...I totally get it...I had to take a shower after I posted ;)

Comment: And BRC actually made proper #1 on a couple of national charts too... not sure how I forgot this one!

Comment: I once studied 'ABHeart' [as was all we could do to call it without people overhearing us] as en exercise in sound engineering. It really is a fabulously-recorded track, even if it makes your sensibilities bleed to have to listen to it.  ;)

Comment: Considered a one hit wonder by many, most only know BRC for ABHeart and nothing else.  I think that a lot of those people, outside of country music fans, would be surprised at BRC's success. He has a song called "Wher'm I Gonna Live?" that I love.  Funny and catchy...

Comment: I had the album, as part of that exercise - though I'm pretty sure I never listened to it. definitely one hit wonder in the UK [general perception anyway, if not strictly]

Comment: Yeah, he did well in the US and Canada.  In the UK that album went gold with ABHeart reaching #3, "Could've Been Me" #24 and "These Boots Are Made for Walkin'" topping out at #63.  The beginning and end of his UK career :)

Comment: I thought "Could've Been Me" was a very well-written song (by Reed Nielsen and Monty Powell).  If that had been the big hit instead of "Achy Breaky Heart", our impression of Billy Ray Cyrus would have been very different.

Comment: Although there are some other great answers (depending on exactly how the question is interpreted!), I'll accept this one for now as 1) it seems both reached an overall (not genre-specific) #1 in one or more countries and 2) they did so as individuals rather than part of a group.

Answer (score 17):

**Johnny Cash:**

- "I Walk the Line" (1956) #1 US Country
- "There You Go" (1956) #1 US Country
- "Ballad of a Teenage Queen" (1958) #1 US Country
- "Guess Things Happen That Way" (1958) #1 US Country
- "Don't Take Your Guns to Town" (1959) #1 US Country
- "Ring of Fire" (1963) #1 US Country
- "Understand Your Man" (1964) #1 US Country
- "Rosanna's Going Wild" (1967) #1 Canadian Country, #2 US Country
- "Folsom Prison Blues" (1968) #1 US Country, #1 US Canadian Country
- "Daddy Sang Bass" (1968) #1 US Country, #1 US Canadian Country
- "A Boy Named Sue" (1969) #1 US Country, #1 US Adult Contemporary, #1 US Canadian Country, #1 Canadian Adult Contemporary, #2 US Pop (Hot 100)
- "Blistered" (1969) #1 Canadian Country, #4 US Country
- "If I Were a Carpenter" w/June Carter Cash (1969) #1 Canadian Country, #2 US Country
- "Sunday Mornin' Comin' Down" (1970) #1 US Country, #1 US Canadian Country
- "Flesh and Blood" (1970) #1 US Country, #1 US Canadian Country
- "A Thing Called Love" (1971) #1 Canadian Country, #2 US Country
- "Kate" (1972) #1 Canadian Country, #2 US Country
- "Oney" (1972) #1 Canadian Country, #2 US Country
- "Any Old Wind That Blows" (1972) #1 Canadian Country, #3 US Country
- "One Piece at a Time" (1976) #1 US Country, #1 US Canadian Country, #1 Canadian Adult Contemporary
- "(Ghost) Riders in the Sky" (1979) #1 Canadian Country, #2 US Country

**Rosanne Cash:**

- "Seven Year Ache" (1981) #1 US Country
- "My Baby Thinks He's a Train" (1981) #1 US Country
- "Blue Moon with Heartache" (1981) #1 US Country
- "I Don't Know Why You Don't Want Me" (1985) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country
- "Never Be You" (1985) #1 US Country, #2 Canadian Country
- "The Way We Make a Broken Heart" (1987) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country
- "Tennessee Flat Top Box" (1987) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country
- "If You Change Your Mind" (1988) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country
- "Runaway Train" (1988) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country
- "I Don't Want to Spoil the Party"    (1989) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country

Comment: Must be a candidate for parent/child with the most individual #1s each!

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, surely @topo_morto ;)

Comment: @TimMalone these are all genre-specific charts, I think? I accepted the Cyruses as they've both made it to #1 in proper full national charts.

Answer (score 16):

**Nat "King" Cole:**

- "Mona Lisa" (1950) #1 Seller in Stores, #1 Played by Jockeys, #1 Played in Jukeboxes
- “Ramblin’ Rose” (1962) #1 Adult Contemporary, #2 Pop, #7 R&B

**Natalie Cole:**

- "This Will Be" (1975) #1 US R&B
- "Inseparable" (1975) #1 US R&B
- "Sophisticated Lady (She's a Different Lady)" (1976) #1 US R&B
- "I've Got Love on My Mind" (1977) #1 US R&B
- "Our Love" (1977) #1 US R&B
- "Miss You Like Crazy" (1989) #1 US R&B

Answer (score 14):

**Hank Williams:**

- "Lovesick Blues" (1949) #1 US Country
- "Long Gone Lonesome Blues" (1950) #1 US Country
- "Why Don't You Love Me" (1950) #1 US Country
- "Moanin' the Blues" (1950) #1 US Country
- "Cold, Cold Heart" (1951) #1 US Country
- "Hey Good Lookin'" (1951) #1 US Country
- "Jambalaya (On the Bayou)" (1952) #1 US Country
- "I'll Never Get Out of This World Alive" (1952) #1 US Country
- "Kaw-Liga" (1953) #1 US Country
- "Take These Chains from My Heart" (1953) #1 US Country

**Hank Williams Jr.:**

- "Eleven Roses" (1972) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country
- "Whiskey Bent and Hell Bound" (1979) #1 Canadian Country
- "Texas Women" (1981) #1 US Country
- "Dixie on My Mind" (1981) #1 US Country
- "All My Rowdy Friends (Have Settled Down)" (1981) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country
- "Honky Tonkin'" (1982) #1 US Country
- "I'm for Love" (1985) #1 US Country
- "Ain't Misbehavin'" (1986) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country
- "Mind Your Own Business" (1986) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country
- "Born to Boogie" (1987) #1 US Country, #1 Canadian Country

Answer (score 13):

**John Lennon**

"(Just Like) Starting Over" (1980) #1 US, UK & several other countries (plus several other solo hits and quite a few with a band he was in)

**Julian Lennon**

"Too Late for Goodbyes" (1984) #1 US Adult Contemporary (plus 2 US Rock #1s)

---

**Pat Boone**

"Love Letters in the Sand" (1957) #1 US (plus other US & UK #1s but none that were #1 in both, oddly)

**Debby Boone**

"You Light Up My Life" (1977) #1 US, US AC, Canada & Canada AC

Comment: Good find on the Boone one - that ticks all the boxes just like the Cyrus one I think!

Comment: I have become somewhat obsessed by this question!

Answer (score 12):

The Mamas and Papas hit number 1 with [*Monday, Monday*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mamas_%26_the_Papas#Singles) in 1966 on both Billboard and Cashbox.

One Mama, Michelle Phillips, and one Papa, John Phillips had a daughter, Chynna Phillips, who got together with two sisters, Carnie and Wendy Wilson to form the band Wilson Phillips.
In the early 1990's, Wilson Phillips had 3 number one hits [*(Hold On, Release me* and *You're in Love)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_Phillips#Singles)

...and oh yeah - Carnie and Wendy were given their surname by their dad Brian, who had [a band with his brothers Dennis and Carl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beach_Boys) that had some commercial success too.

Comment: I realize that none of these are solo acts, but since in all three cases there are multiple family members in the groups, it seems like it is worth mentioning.  :-)

Answer (score 10):

Late to the party, but I've found another parent-child combo with individual #1 singles.

**Julio Iglesias**

- "[Lo Mejor de Tu Vida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo_Mejor_de_Tu_Vida)" (1987) #1 US Billboard Hot Latin Tracks
- "[Que No Se Rompa la Noche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Que_No_Se_Rompa_la_Noche)" (1987) #1 US Billboard Hot Latin Tracks

**Enrique Iglesias**

- "[Bailamos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailamos)" (1999) #1 Billboard Hot 100
- "[Be With You](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Be_with_You_(Enrique_Iglesias_song))" (2000) #1 Billboard Hot 100

Enrique Iglesias also has [24 #1 singles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enrique_Iglesias_discography#Spanish-language_singles) on the Billboard Hot Latin Tracks chart as a solo artist, and [two additional #1 singles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enrique_Iglesias_discography#As_featured_artist) on that chart as a featured artist.

Answer (score 8):

My mind went immediately to Dylan, but, upon further digging, it turns out he never had a #1 song that he performed himself, even though his son, Jakob had. Even with the Traveling Wilburys, while they had several #2s, no #1s. *However*, since you didn't exclude *writing* a #1 song even if they didn't perform it, one could count [Dylan's writing of a song that eventually became Wagon Wheel by Darius Rucker](http://ultimateclassicrock.com/bob-dylan-wagon-wheel/).

So, if that counts...

**Bob Dylan**

- ["Wagon Wheel"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon_Wheel_%28song%29#Darius_Rucker_version) (written by Dylan ~1973, performed by Darius Rucker (2013) #1 on various charts including US Billboard Country Airplay
- UPDATE...another 'written by' #1: ["Mr. Tambourine Man"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Tambourine_Man#The_Byrds.27_version) (1965, as performed by The Byrds in 1965) #1 on Billboard Hot 100

**Jakob Dylan**

- ["One Headlight"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Headlight) (1996) #1 on multiple charts including US Billboard Mainstream Rock

---

And though it only made it to #1 on one specific chart, I think Willow's song lets her be included on this list as well:

**Will Smith**

- [Several songs on several charts solo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Smith_discography#Singles) and a [couple as a part of DJ Jazzy Jeff and the Fresh Prince](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJ_Jazzy_Jeff_%26_The_Fresh_Prince_discography#Singles) specifically ["Summertime"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summertime_(DJ_Jazzy_Jeff_%26_The_Fresh_Prince_song)) (1991) #1 on multiple charts including U.S. Billboard Hot Rap Singles

**Willow Smith**

- ["Whip my Hair"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whip_My_Hair) (2010) #1 on the UK R&B (Official Charts Company)

Comment: While Jakob is a fine musician, he doesn't have a Nobel Prize.